# how do you override setFrame for a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I wanted to override setframe so that it centers the label as well, however doing something like:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    [self setFrame:frame};
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.superview.center.x, kNavigationBarFrameHeight/2);
}
```

gives me an infinite loop. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to call `[super setFrame:frame]`.

That will call UILabel's implementation of `setFrame` and not your own. That is what is causing your infinite loop.